# Database cursor doesn't insert any values into my table, but there is no error when running the codes

Tags: oracle, loops, iteration, database-cursor

I am new to Oracle programming (started coding a month ago).

I've written the following codes, which involves using a cursor to iteratively insert values into a table. However after I run the codes, nothing is inserted into the table. What puzzles me is, there is no error when I run the codes.

```
begin
  for CURSOR_NAME in (
                   select column_name
                   from TABLE_AAA
                   )
  loop

    insert into TEST_TABLE_5    
    (A, B, C, D)

    select 
       ...
       
from SOME_TABLE 
where 

<some conditions that involve CURSOR_NAME.column_name> 


 end loop;
end;
```

Could you please advise where I should start to troubleshoot? If there're error when running the codes, I'd check Oracle Documentations to resolve the error. But if there's no error, don't know where to start.

I did pick a sample value from TABLE_AAA and plugged into the section within the LOOP to test it out. The value has been inserted into TEST_TABLE_5, so the section within the LOOP is correct.

I'm 100% certain there are data that meet the conditions in the following clause, so in theory some data should've been inserted into TEST_TABLE_5.

```
<some conditions that involve CURSOR_NAME.column_name>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried to debug?  Are you stepping through the code in, say, SQL Developer?  Does the code enter the loop?  You could look at `sql%rowcount` after running the `insert` statement to determine how many rows the `insert` statement inserted.  If you're not stepping through the code in a debugger, the old school way would be to add a bunch of `dbms_output.put_line` statements to your code that tell you whether (and how many) times you iterated through the loop, whether statements were inserting the expected number of rows, etc.

Comment: did you do a commit?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of possibilities to iterate all rows of a table. The most simple:

```
for i in (select column1, column2, ... from table1) loop
  dbms_output.put_line(i.column1);
end loop;
```